# How to generate random passwords in SQL Server using stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server supports many applications and most applications have a feature to  store passwords. Is there any tip from which I can cover a simple stored procedure to generate random passwords that can be incorporated into my applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is GUID good enough for a password? use `NEWID()` to generate new GUID and pass it as a password.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the tutorial [SQL Password Generator](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/random-password-generator-sql-stored-procedure.aspx) . You will find how you can customize password generator and SQL source codes of a sample stored procedure which generates random password according to the rules defined in customization

As a result you will be creating random passwords by executing following script

```
DECLARE @pwd varchar(25)
EXECUTE Generate_Password @pwd OUTPUT
SELECT @pwd
```

I hope it helps,